# Django: Can I use Subquery with more than one database?

Tags: django, subquery

I have two 2 tables in different databases.

```
# Database A
class Category(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)

# Database B
class Hero(models.Model):
    # ...
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    category = models.ForeignKey(Category, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    benevolence_factor = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField(
        help_text="How benevolent this hero is?",
        default=50
    )
```

Can I use Subquery like this:

```
hero_qs = Hero.objects.filter(
    category=OuterRef("pk")
).order_by("-benevolence_factor")
Category.objects.all().annotate(
    most_benevolent_hero=Subquery(
        hero_qs.values('name')[:1]
    )
)
```

Actually, I found this:
[https://books.agiliq.com/projects/django-orm-cookbook/en/latest/subquery.html](https://stackoverflow.com)

but no example with different databases.

Comment: you sure? 2 Database? or You meant Models?

Comment: I meant 2 models in 2 different databases ?